# Where is the current KDE Plasma 5 theme saved?

Tags: kde, themes, customization, plasma, plasma-5

I'm using KDE Neon with Plasma 5.20.0, based on Ubuntu 20.04

I want to switch to another theme while I still keep the old one so I can restore it later. Where's the current theme with all the customizations like cursor, window decorations and so on?

Is there a way to export the current Plasma theme as a loadable theme that will show in the system settings?

**EDIT 1:** I found a directory (`~/.local/share/aurorae/themes`) that contains some folders with the themes I'm currently using in a combination. Is this the right location? Can I safely backup this?

**EDIT 2:** I found out that this directory is for installed window decorations. I can only find the installed themes, but not themes that are in use. Is there any config file or something with **active** themes?

Comment: On the location of theme folders and files, see [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1392795/925128).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this GitHub](https://github.com/shalva97/kde-configuration-files), currently enabled themes are stored in the `~/.config` directory.

> **Appearance**
>
> - Global Theme
>
> *.config/kdeglobals*
>
> *.config/kscreenlockerrc*
>
> *.config/kwinrc*
>
> *.config/gtkrc*
>
> .config/gtkrc-2.0
>
> - Plasma Style
>
> *.config/plasmarc*
>
> - Application Style
>
> *.config/kdeglobals*
>
> 1. Window Decorations
>
> *.config/kwinrc*
>
> - Colors
>
> *.config/kdeglobals*
>
> *.config/Trolltech.conf*
>
> - Fonts
>
> 1. Fonts
>
> *.config/kdeglobals*
>
> *.config/kcmfonts*
>
> - Icons
>
> *.config/kdeglobals*
>
> - Cursors
>
> *.config/kcminputrc*

So, I can now write a simple shell script that will save these files into a *zip* file and a script that will extract a *zip* file into this directory.