# How Do I Set All KDE Look And Feel Settings In A Script?

Tags: bash, kde, themes

There are multiple parts to a system theme in KDE in different parts of the System Settings. e.g.

- Global Theme
- Plasma Style
- Icons
- Window Decorations
- Desktop Wallpaper
- Login Screen (SDDM)
- Boot Splash Screen
- Splash Screen

There are probably more parts but these are the ones I have customised.

All of these can be downloaded from the store and you can apply various different parts manually via the System Settings GUI to create a look and feel that you like.

However, when I re-install or install on a new PC I would like to be able to set all these easily without having to remember all my settings and apply them one by one.

How can I script all these settings so that I have a way to easily get a consistent look and feel each time?

Answer (score 1):

From my question I asked few weeks ago ( [Where is the current KDE Plasma 5 theme saved?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1285086/where-is-the-current-kde-plasma-5-theme-saved) ):

> According to [this GitHub](https://github.com/shalva97/kde-configuration-files), currently enabled themes are stored in the `~/.config` directory.
> **Appearance**
>
> - Global Theme
>
> *.config/kdeglobals*
>
> *.config/kscreenlockerrc*
>
> *.config/kwinrc*
>
> *.config/gtkrc*
>
> .config/gtkrc-2.0
>
> - Plasma Style
>
> *.config/plasmarc*
>
> - Application Style
>
> *.config/kdeglobals*
>
> 1. Window Decorations
>
> *.config/kwinrc*
>
> - Colors
>
> *.config/kdeglobals*
>
> *.config/Trolltech.conf*
>
> - Fonts
>
> 1. Fonts
>
> *.config/kdeglobals*
>
> *.config/kcmfonts*
>
> - Icons
>
> *.config/kdeglobals*
>
> - Cursors
>
> *.config/kcminputrc*
>
> So, I can now write a simple shell script that will save these files into a *zip* file and a script that will extract a *zip* file into this directory.

**Note:** This works only if you have all the themes **installed**. That means, you'll need to write a script that will check if these themes are installed before proceeding further. The installed themes have their own location too (it was somewhere in ~/.share/ if I remember correctly).

Answer (score 0):

**Plasma Configuration Saver** is an applet to do exactly this (with the exception of SDDM and Plymouth themes, which are system-wide settings).

It can be added installed as a widget.

https://store.kde.org/p/1298955